# AAD login prompt in a console app (.NET Framework) - can you use the oauth2 *non v2.0* endpoint?

Tags: c#, azure-ad-msal

So I've created an Azure Function that is secured with AAD.

I'm trying to give a prompt to the user so that I can get the bearer token to call my Azure Function.

I'm currently trying the `PublicClientApplication.AcquireTokenAsync` method (from the namespace `Microsoft.Identity.Client`) - where I'm using the App Id of the Azure function and I don't need to specify a resource, but I'm not getting the right token back.

This is the code I have so far:

```cs
string[] scopes = new string[] { "profile", "email", "openid" };
string ClientId = "[Client ID of Azure Function]";
string Tenant = "[tenant guid]";
string Instance = "https://login.windows.net/";
var _clientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
    .WithAuthority($"{Instance}{Tenant}")
    .WithDefaultRedirectUri()
    .Build();
var accounts = _clientApp.GetAccountsAsync().Result;

var authResult = _clientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
            .WithAccount(accounts.FirstOrDefault())
            .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)
            .ExecuteAsync().Result;
var x = authResult.AccessToken;  //audience for this is the Client id for Microsoft Graph
var y = authResult.IdToken;      //audience for this is the Client id for my Azure Function
```

What I've noticed is that this uses the 'v2.0' endpoint:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenantguid]/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

Hence, the id_token I get back does not work.

However, after lots of debugging and trial and error, I noticed that when I remove the `/v2.0` part from the URL (using Fiddler), the resulting id_token works!

The expected jwt should look like this:

```
{
  "aud": "[Client id of my Azure Function]",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/[tenant guid]/", //without a /v2.0 at the end
   ...
}
```

How do I get it to not use the v2.0 endpoint?

Edit: I've modified my Azure Function to accept v2.0 tokens, but just out of curiosity, I still want to know how to use this API without v2.0.

Thanks so much!

Sidenote: I've already tried creating a "client" to call it, using the `authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync` method (from the namespace `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory`).
This method does not work because my organization doesn't allow this - I get this error in the login prompt, after authentication: "[my client app] needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to this app before you can use it."

Answer (score 0):

Just change the scopes value to `{client_id/.default}`. It will looks like

```
string[] scopes = new string[] {"client_id_of_yourFunction/.default"};
```

Reference:

[The /.default scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#the-default-scope)

**Update:**

If you want to call v1.0 endpoint, you need to use adal(Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory) instead of msal.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datacatalog/authenticate-a-client-app

Comment: I didn't know about this, but this still returns a token issued by https://login.microsoftonline.com/clientid/v2.0 - and if I use this scope to get the Bearer token, the value of `req.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` in the Azure Function is empty.

Comment: @AmbroseLeung Since you are using msal,that's why you got v2.0, but I don't think this is the cause. In Azure function, you can not get the username by using `req.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`, but you can get the user information in the header,  you can check the headers `req.headers`

Comment: @AmbroseLeung Access user claims, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#access-user-claims

Comment: Doing this still returns a token issued by `login.microsoftonline.com/clientid/v2.0`, but I was looking for a way to get a token issued by `login.microsoftonline.com/clientid/` without the v2.0

Comment: Thanks, but using ADAL involves different code (and you have to create a useless client app registration)

Answer (score 0):

At this point, it doesn't seem that there is a way to send it to the non v2.0 endpoint (other than hotpatching the dll).

I used [DNSpy](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy/releases) to debug and saw that "v2.0" is hardcoded into the OpenId Discovery Endpoint (this is in an internal class).

I can confirm that when I changed the hardcoded string (to remove the v2.0 part, it went to the non v2.0 endpoint.(https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenantid]/.well-known/openid-configuration - without the /v2.0).

See here for decompiled code:

```cs
namespace Microsoft.Identity.Client.Instance
{
    // Token: 0x0200022F RID: 559
    internal class AadOpenIdConfigurationEndpointManager : IOpenIdConfigurationEndpointManager
    {
        // Token: 0x060015E8 RID: 5608 RVA: 0x00049C1F File Offset: 0x00047E1F
        public AadOpenIdConfigurationEndpointManager(IServiceBundle serviceBundle)
        {
            this._serviceBundle = serviceBundle;
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        // Token: 0x060015E9 RID: 5609 RVA: 0x00049C30 File Offset: 0x00047E30
        public async Task<string> ValidateAuthorityAndGetOpenIdDiscoveryEndpointAsync(AuthorityInfo authorityInfo, string userPrincipalName, RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(authorityInfo.CanonicalAuthority);
            if (authorityInfo.ValidateAuthority && !KnownMetadataProvider.IsKnownEnvironment(uri.Host))
            {
                await this._serviceBundle.InstanceDiscoveryManager.GetMetadataEntryAsync(authorityInfo.CanonicalAuthority, requestContext).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            return authorityInfo.CanonicalAuthority + "v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration";
        }

        // Token: 0x04000957 RID: 2391
        private readonly IServiceBundle _serviceBundle;
    }
}
```